# What are some ways to make the main thread wait for all working threads to complete?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I know the standard way with pthreads is to use pthread_join(), but what are good alternatives? I am currently using the sleep() to force the main thread to wait. Is that bad practice?

Comment: Why do you need alternatives to `join()`?

Comment: `sleep()` (and all its variants) is *not* a synchronization primitive. Yeah, using `sleep` for this is pretty bad practice.

Comment: Why using pthread when C++ has threading stuff in it's standard library?

Comment: Using sleep to synchronise should be considered a joke, not a serious solution to a hard technical problem. **Use join.**

Answer (score 2):

It is bad practice to use sleep.

Simple example: With sleep your main thread sleeps an amount of time and you have no control if the thread finished before the timeout. So your processing seems to take more time it acually needs for the user. On the other hand if sleep is over you must be sure that the thread actually finished its job, so you will have to signal something to the main thread.

With pthread_join() you do not face these problems.

Comment: I have seen good uses of `sleep` around threads (essentially semi-busy waiting). It all depends on what your threads are for / doing. The rest I agree with, upvoted :)